# How to apply layout inheritance to android views programmatically?

Tags: android, inheritance

I have a TextView that is generated programmatically (and not in xml layout file).

```
TextView myTextView = new TextView(this);
```

How do I apply all the attributes of the parent of this TextView (that is NOT created programmatically and it's stored in xml ) to it via code? (How do I inherit programmatically?)

Answer (score 0):

Suppose your Root xml is-

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/root_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">
</LinearLayout>
```

You want to add view dynamically to this view. Then set layout params of the parent to the child and set all other properties you want. Lastly add the view to the root and enjoy. In your Activity/Fragment use code like this-

```
LinearLayout rootLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.root_layout);
TextView textView = new TextView(context);
LinearLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
layoutParams.gravity = Gravity.CENTER;
textView.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
textView.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
textView.setText("Hello");
rootLayout.addView(textView);
```

**Note:** If your root layout is a RelativeLayout then use RelativeLayout.LayoutParams and for others accordingly.